# PHP form check box issue

Tags: php, forms, post, checkbox, handle

I have a simple form that I'm trying to add a checkbox to, I have everything on the form setup correctly but when I try to handle the check box I'm only able to make echos work. I'm trying set whether the box is checked as a yes or no and store that yes/no in a variable, here is what I have in my handle form for the checkbox:

```
    if(isset($_POST['race']) && 
   $_POST['race'] == 'Yes') 
{
    $race1 == "yes";
}
else
{
    $race1 == "No";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this code snippet relates to a form.  Can you provide your form html?

Comment: if you are trying to default a checkbox to checked add the attribute `checked="checked"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the single equal sign when assigning values. Double equals does a comparison.

```
if(isset($_POST['race']) && $_POST['race'] == 'Yes') 
{
  $race1 = "yes";
}
else
{
  $race1 = "No";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` is a comparison operator. You need to use attribution operator `=`

```
if (isset($_POST['race']) &&
    strtolower($_POST['race']) == 'yes') 
{
    $race1 = 'yes';
}
else
{
    $race1 = 'No';
}
```